# import sharepoint 2007 web site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss

I have sharepoint 2007 site and i export this site and i want to import it to another site can i import it to existing site not create new one?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use stsadm.

To export:

stsadm -o export -url [URL HERE] -filename [path] -versions 4

ststadm -o import -url [NEW URL] -filname [path]

Those should work.